# Handle JSON parse error in Jersey

Tags: java, json, exception, jersey

How can I intercept a parse error in my Jersey REST application? I already registered an `ExceptionMapper<Exception>` but those don't get caught.

It returns the following to the client

```
Unexpected character ('y' (code 121)): expected a valid value (number,
  String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
  at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@161d5f3;
  line: 1, column: 92]
```

But I want to send my own Response.

Comment: How did you define and register your ExceptionMapper? Are you sure it's registered and applicable for the exception being thrown?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure because it captures other exceptions. It should capture any exception deriving from Exception. I also tried with Throwable just to be sure.

Comment: You can always catch this exception and return appropriate Response.

Comment: This is the question. How do I catch this exception? Where?

Comment: Don't really know about Jersey, but in RESTEasy exception mappers to classes like `Exception` and `Throwable` have, by design, no effect. Put a `System.out.println()` and throw an `Exception` on purpose just to check if yours is really set up.

Comment: Yes, my exception mapper works, but not for those...

Comment: For anyone coming across this, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35681468/5483217) is the answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing however your ExceptionMapper is registered, it isn't being applied to other packages, where you're invoking the Jersey library code to parse JSON.

Surround all calls to Jersey for parsing in a Try{    }catch() block, where the catch should return an error code and not process further.

Alternatively, it looks like Tomcat might be throwing the error before it even gets to your application. Maybe an issue with the way it is configured, or the way the client is communicating? Is this plaintext HTTP?

Comment: I'm not calling jersey; jersey calls my code. And I'm not using tomcat.