# Jersey Custom Exception Mapper for Invalid Json String

Tags: java, json, rest, validation, jersey

I am working on an application for which I required to build the response in case an invalid JSON payload is sent in the request.

Currently the exception message received at the server end is **Unexpected character ('"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@310db662; line: 13, column: 7]**

This is how I'm trying to achieve it ...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

@Provider
public class JsonParseExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<JsonProcessingException> {

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(JsonParseExceptionMapper.class.getName());

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(final JsonProcessingException ex) {

        System.out.println("inside json parse exception mappper");

        logger.error(messages.toString());
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(messages).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
}
```

I also have a similar ExceptionMapper which catches the ConstraintViolationException which is working fine.

I also tried a few different exceptions as suggested over the internet, to name a few

```
JsonProcessingException
BadRequestException
JsonParseException
InvalidFormatException
ConstraintDeclarationException
```

But None of the above exceptions seem to work in this case. Does anyone have any idea as to which exception should be used in conjunction with the ExceptionMapper to catch such cases.
Also, I guess it is possible to have more than one ExceptionMapper implementations running parallel to each other. Please correct if I'm wrong.

**Edit: This is what I mean by an invalid JSON Payload, look out for the missing comma before checksum**

```
{
    "payload": {
        "name":"rachel",
        "employeeid":"23443"
    }
    "checksum":""
}
```

Jersey v2.22.1
Spring v4.2.4-RELEASE

**For some reason I'm not able to comment on any of the posts !!! Even the edit window has issues, I can't see any icon !!**

I tried using RuntimeException, Exception and IOException as well but the ExceptionMapper didn't work for them too. I guess it takes a specific time of exception like the ConstraintViolationException which is in use with another ExceptionMapper and that one is working fine.

some part of web.xml

            jersey.config.beanValidation.enableOutputValidationErrorEntity.server
            true
        
        
            jersey.config.server.disableMoxyJson
            true

Comment: have you registered the mapper in the config ? What kind of json parser do you use ?

Comment: yes the mapper is registered using @Provider. I am using codehaus and using spring for DI. Jersey v 2.22.1

Comment: For me it looks like that the code you've provided is correct (except missing import for JsonProcessingException which is caused I guess by the change of the post here, on the site). You can try to catch IOException or even Exception/RuntimeException to make sure that the provider is called at all. Also make sure that it is located inside of  `jersey.config.server.provider.classpath` (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/appendix-properties.html)

Comment: jersey is able to locate the mapper as it is annotated with the @Provider and the package is also set to be looked up by jersey. I also tried using Exception, RuntimeException and IOException but they didn't work either

Comment: I'm using Java 1.8 does that has anything to do with this ... though I don't think so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially I had registered JacksonFeature.class for Json Parsing which uses its own ExceptionMapper for JsonParseException.

I changed it to JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class.

I'm now able to use my custom JsonParseExceptionMapper.

Had to change certain dependencies !!

Comment: Dude, you just saved my life... I am using Jersey and Embedded Jetty, so I had to do this: `final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);
        resourceConfig.packages(PACKAGES);`

Comment: nice to know. happy coding.